# How to add a user_id label to request_total function in starlette_exporter library?

Tags: python, prometheus

I use a standard library starlette_exporter, function to count the number of requests transfer this data to Prometheus, I need to add a user_id label, please tell me where I can pass the user_id to Counter?

library use: https://github.com/stephenhillier/starlette_exporter

My current code:
`

```
  metric_name = f"{self.prefix}_request_total"
            if metric_name not in PrometheusMiddleware._metrics:
                PrometheusMiddleware._metrics[metric_name] = Counter(
                    metric_name,
                    "Total HTTP request",
                    (
                        "method",
                        "path",
                        "status_code",
                        "app_name",
                        *self._default_label_keys(),
                    ),
                )

            return PrometheusMiddleware._metrics[metric_name]
```

The output of my function:

> appname_request_total{app_name="appname",method="GET", path="api/appname/user/10", status_code="200"}

I need for Example:

> appname_request_total{app_name="appname",method="GET", path="api/appname/user/10", user_id="10", status_code="200"}

Comment: Since you are using custom metrics here, adding lable should be fairly easy: 1. add label `user_id` to list, you are passing while creating metric (after tenth line of code you provided), 2. add actual user id as an additional parameter identifying metrics while increasing it (code you haven't provided)